# Strange stack at android crash report

Tags: java, android, firebase, crash-reports

I receive some crash reports from android (with java.lang.NullPointerException), but **I don't understand what mean __null __ in stacktrace** below:

```
at __null__.formatElapsedTime(MainActivity.java)
at __null__.access$102(MainActivity.java)
at __null__.access$200(MainActivity.java)
at __null__.access$500(MainActivity.java)
at ru.yandex.subbota_job.multiplicationtable.MainActivity.onEnterPressed(MainActivity.java)
at ru.yandex.subbota_job.multiplicationtable.KeyboardFragment.onClick(KeyboardFragment.java)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18789)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

And I don't understand what access$xxx functions is?

Furthermore, formatElapsedTime is not called from onEnterPressed neither directly nor indirectly! That is absolutely! formatElapsedTime is called from timer thread through runOnUiThread. This is very rare bug has occurred for the second time only on two different devices.

Help, please, by any idea!
I have a lot of **__null__**

.

Comment: Please share your `MainActivity`'s code

Comment: do you have any libraries?

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE, MainActivity is long enough. What part of it will you wish see?

Comment: @rala, support library only

Comment: Those access$xxx are inner/anonymous classes, could be interface implementations for example. You state that formatElapsedTime is not called from onEnterPressed, but your stacktrace states otherwise. Please find out that path and share it

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE, I've shared it.

Comment: Is that the entire stack trace, or are there lines above the first `__null__`?

Comment: @WillBeason, This is entire stack trace without one line on the top of stack.

Comment: Ah, yes, then this is the behavior I described in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the old behavior when the Firebase stack trace deobfuscator was unable to unambiguously determine which of several methods was the original method for an obfuscated stack frame in a stack trace. This should not happen for future crashes.

[Further explanation here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42519722/2592962)