# "__null__" class names in Firebase Crash Reporting stacktraces

Tags: android, firebase-crash-reporting

I have recently integrated my app with Firebase Crash Reporting. Some stacktraces look quite strange, having lines with '__null__' classnames:

```
Exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{349094da position=164 id=-1, oldPos=132, pLpos:132 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
    __null__.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.recycleChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.recycleViewsFromStart (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.recycleByLayoutState (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.fill (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.layoutChunk (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.findFirstVisibleChildClosestToStart (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.findReferenceChild (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.findOneVisibleChild (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.onFocusSearchFailed (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.prepareForDrop (LinearLayoutManager.java)
android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition (LinearLayoutManager.java)
    __null__.onLayoutChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java)
...
```

I am using ProGuard, but mapping file is uploaded.

Can someone explain why I am having '__null__' in place of class names and how to fix it?

There is already post with similar question: [Strange stack at android crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544446/strange-stack-at-android-crash-report/41630001#41630001) but author answered himself and accepted it with no actual answer for the question.

Comment: This might be some previous version of your application which is crashing.

Comment: This is crash of the latest version (actually this is first version where Firebase Crash Reporting is integrated). Moreover classes missing names are from Recycler View lib, which are not part of my app source code

Comment: Update your `RecyclerView` version then?

Comment: I can update RecyclerView, but I do not see how it will solve issue with null class names. I noticed that issue is happening not only to RecyclerView classes, but also to classes of my app, which are up to date.. so it's not about using previous versions definitely.

Comment: I have a lot of such crashes from firebase and from google console but nobody can explain it(

Comment: Could you contact the Firebase support team and file a bug report with information about your project?  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @DougStevenson I have done it already. 3-3030000015472 is number of ticket(?). I was assured that the appeal was sent to the "right team")

Comment: @AlexeySubbota Yes, we received your report.  Thank you for sending it.  You should receive an update when the problem is actually fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in the Firebase Crash Reporting console.  A fix is scheduled and should be available soon.

Comment: thanks for an answer. where I can see list of Firebase bugs and track their progress?

Comment: Sorry, there's no public bug tracker for Firebase at the moment.

Comment: @DougStevenson Who are know about this bug? I have received same ___null___ in google console crash stacktrace.