# What is '<OR>' in firebase crash stack?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

What is `<OR>` in the firebase crash stack?

```
android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected (Activity.java:2566)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected (FragmentActivity.java)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected (AppCompatActivity.java)
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected (WindowCallbackWrapper.java)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreate (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.setSupportActionBar (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.findViewById (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.onConfigurationChanged (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.onSubDecorInstalled (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.onPanelClosed (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.onMenuItemSelected (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.onMenuModeChange (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.startSupportActionModeFromWindow (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.onKeyShortcut (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.shouldInheritContext (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.openPanel (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.initializePanelDecor (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.reopenMenu (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.closePanel (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.callOnPanelClosed (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.findMenuPanel (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.getPanelState (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
<OR>.performPanelShortcut (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.setDefaultShowAsAction (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addMenuPresenter (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addMenuPresenter (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.dispatchSubMenuSelected (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.saveActionViewStates (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.getActionViewStatesKey (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setCallback (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addInternal (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.createNewMenuItem (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.removeItemAtInt (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setExclusiveItemChecked (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findGroupIndex (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.dispatchMenuItemSelected (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findInsertIndex (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findItemsWithShortcutForKey (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findItemWithShortcutForKey (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.performItemAction (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.performItemAction (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.close (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.onItemVisibleChanged (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderInternal (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderTitleInt (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderIconInt (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderViewInt (MenuBuilder.java)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke (MenuItemImpl.java)
<OR>.setCheckedInt (MenuItemImpl.java)
<OR>.setShowAsActionFlags (MenuItemImpl.java)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.setDefaultShowAsAction (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addMenuPresenter (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addMenuPresenter (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.dispatchSubMenuSelected (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.saveActionViewStates (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.getActionViewStatesKey (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setCallback (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addInternal (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.createNewMenuItem (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.removeItemAtInt (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setExclusiveItemChecked (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findGroupIndex (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.dispatchMenuItemSelected (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findInsertIndex (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findItemsWithShortcutForKey (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findItemWithShortcutForKey (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.performItemAction (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.performItemAction (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.close (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.onItemVisibleChanged (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderInternal (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderTitleInt (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderIconInt (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderViewInt (MenuBuilder.java)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.setDefaultShowAsAction (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addMenuPresenter (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addMenuPresenter (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.dispatchSubMenuSelected (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.saveActionViewStates (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.getActionViewStatesKey (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setCallback (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addInternal (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.createNewMenuItem (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.removeItemAtInt (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setExclusiveItemChecked (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findGroupIndex (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.dispatchMenuItemSelected (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findInsertIndex (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findItemsWithShortcutForKey (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.findItemWithShortcutForKey (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.performItemAction (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.performItemAction (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.close (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.onItemVisibleChanged (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderInternal (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderTitleInt (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderIconInt (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.setHeaderViewInt (MenuBuilder.java)
android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.measureChildForCells (ActionMenuView.java)
<OR>.isOverflowReserved (ActionMenuView.java)
<OR>.generateLayoutParams (ActionMenuView.java)
<OR>.generateLayoutParams (ActionMenuView.java)
<OR>.invokeItem (ActionMenuView.java)
<OR>.initialize (ActionMenuView.java)
<OR>.setMenuCallbacks (ActionMenuView.java)
<OR>.hasSupportDividerBeforeChildAt (ActionMenuView.java)
android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick (ActionMenuItemView.java)
android.view.View.performClick (View.java:4211)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:17446)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:725)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:153)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5299)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:833)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:600)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: This question is vague.  Could you share some detail about where you're seeing this and maybe some details about your project?

Comment: @DougStevenson, I have received this stack trace in firebase console from my andoid application. If you work in firebase support I will send you any information about firbase project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<OR>` indicates that the deobfuscator could not determine which method is the original as there are several potential possibilities. Firebase received an obfuscated stack trace and was unable to unambiguously determine the original stack trace using the provided Proguard file. For example, a deobfuscated stack trace such as:

```
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected (WindowCallbackWrapper.java)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.setDefaultShowAsAction (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addMenuPresenter (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.addMenuPresenter (MenuBuilder.java)
<OR>.dispatchSubMenuSelected (MenuBuilder.java)
```

means that that the first stack frame was unambiguously deobfuscated, but the second stack frame in the stack trace could be any of those four possibilities.

In this case, the ambiguity comes from the fact that both:

1. There are no line numbers to distinguish methods, and
2. multiple methods with different signatures were obfuscated to the same string.

During the shrinking phase, Proguard may be configured to strip line numbers. To avoid this problem, disable that feature.

Obfuscation is not guaranteed to be invertible on stack traces without line numbers as that is not one of the requirements for a valid Proguard mapping. Proguard is only guaranteed to invertibly obfuscate *code*, not *stack traces*. Proguard files include method signatures, so any methods with non-conflicting signatures may be obfuscated to the same string.

For example: `int method(int)` and `String method2(String)` may both be obfuscated to `obf`. From context, the code deobfuscator can see whether obf was passed an int or a String, and can unambiguously choose the correct original method. For a stack trace deobfuscator, the line `MyClass.obf(MyClass.java)` could have come from either `MyClass.method(MyClass.java)` or `MyClass.method2(MyClass.java)`.

Comment: To add to this - if you have ProGuard configured to strip line numbers as part of its shrinking phase, what you are seeing can be a result of that.

Comment: Thank you! It is strange that default proguard-android.txt doesn't contain -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable options.

Comment: @DougStevenson, has this question relation to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544446/strange-stack-at-android-crash-report ?

Comment: @AlexeySubbota Yes, it probably does. That looks like the old behavior.